# Implementing a "Snapshot and Subscribe" in Redis

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I wish to use Redis to create a system which publishes stock quote data to subscribers in an internal network. The problem is that publishing is not enough, as I need to find a way to implement an atomic "get snapshot and then subscribe" mechanism. I'm pretty new to Redis so I'm not sure my solution is the "proper way".

In a given moment each stock has a book of orders which contains at most 10 bids and 10 asks. The publisher receives data for the exchange and should publish them to subscribers.

While the publishing of changes in the order book can be easily done using publish and subscribe, each subscriber that connects also needs to get the snapshot of the current order book of the stock and only then subscribe to changes in the order book.

As I understand, Redis channel never saves information, so the publisher also needs to maintain the complete order book in a hash key (Or a sorted set. I'm not sure which is more appropriate) in addition to publishing changes.
I also understand that a Redis client cannot issue any commands except subscribing and unsubscribing once it subscribes to the first channel.

So, once the subscriber application is up, it needs first to get the key which contains the complete order book and then subscribe to changes in that book. However, this may result in a race condition. A change in the book order can be made after the client got the key containing the current snapshot but before it actually subscribed to changes, resulting a change which it will never see.

As it is not possible to use subscribe and then use get in a single connection, the client application needs two connections to the Redis server. At this point I started thinking that I'm probably not doing things in the proper way if I need more than one connection in the same application. Anyway, my idea is that the client will have a subscribing connection and a query connection. First, it will use the subscribing connection to subscribe to changes in order book, but still won't not enter the loop which process events. Afterwards, it will use the query connection to get the complete snapshot of the book. Finally, it will enter the loop which process events, but as he actually subscribed before taking the snapshot, it is guaranteed that it will not miss any changed that occurred after the snapshot was taken.

Is there any better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I would go with two connections too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found your way already, if not here we goes a personal suggestion:

If you are in javascript land i would recommend having a look on Meteor.js they do somehow achieve the goal you want to achieve, with the default setup you will end up writing to mongodb in order to "update" the GUI for the "end user".

In any case, you might be interested in reading about how meteor's ddp protocol works: https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp/ and https://www.meteor.com/ddp